# Как заблокировать ввод символов в Entry с клавиатуры?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
e=Entry(width=20)
e.pack()
```

Как сделать так,чтобы ничего невозможно было бы набрать на клавиатуре,а также вставить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот так:

```python
from tkinter import *
e = Entry(width=20, state="readonly")
e.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `config`, чтобы изменить параметр `state`. Он может иметь 2 значения - `readonly` и `normal`

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e=Entry(root,width=20)
e.pack()

def onClick():
    if( e['state']=='normal'):
        e.config(state="readonly")#блокируем
        button.config(text="Разблокировать")
    else:
        e.config(state="normal")#разблокируем
        button.config(text="Заблокировать")

#блокировка
button = Button(root,text="Заблокировать",command = onClick)
button.pack()
```